# How do I network enable a plugin for a multisite install via the database?

Tags: plugins, database

The title pretty much sums up the question I have. If you want background then read on.

My multisite install uses an AD integration plugin to log people on. I just upgraded PHP to the latest version but the plugin that I was using is not compatible. It's actually no longer being supported. I found another plugin to take it's place but since the install is set up to us AD integration, I'm not able to log into the dashboard because I deleted the old plugin. So I'm trying to activate the new plugin to see if it will allow me to login.

I found the active plugins for the main site in the wp_options table but I need to find the active ones for my network.

Can anyone help?

Comment: If you rename the plugins folder, that will deactivate them all, and you should then be able to log in with a WP user rather than an AD user.

Comment: Hi @WebElaine, There isn't an active AD plugin on my installation and it still won't allow me to log in. Do you still think it's worth a try?

Comment: In my experience it's always worth trying deactivating all plugins because this forces WP to resume normal out-of-the-box behavior, including logging in as a normal WP user.

Comment: @WebElaine I tried it and it still isn't letting me in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello you can query your database.
e.g.
SELECT * FROM **wp1_**options
WHERE option_name =  'active_plugins'

wp_1 your First Database in the network, then you can see the active Plugins in these site!

Comment: I'm not sure that this will work because I have a multi-site network. The only plugins that I see in this field are the ones that are active for the main (original) site and not the network as a whole.

Comment: there i see that in every site is these separetet, but site 1 is base Site and this is by me wp1_ perhaps by you has an other name!

Comment: Do you mind editing your comment? I'm having trouble understanding it.

Comment: In each site, the plugins are handled separately, but the first site is the base of the network, so are they network-activated plugins!

Comment: I looked on my live server in this same cell and it doesn't have all the network activated plugins listed. There are only four activated plugins listed and those are the four that are activated specifically for the base site alone. There are maybe ten network activated plugins but I don't see them in the database. I hope that gives clarity. Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: Perhaps ca these help
http://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/why-do-you-not-see-all-plugins-on-wordpress-multisite-installs/

Comment: I have found ---yeahh in database -(by me) wp1_sitemeta

meta_key:active_sitewide_plugins !
---stooni

Comment: You're the man, Stooni!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Thank you!!!!